# User profile returned from SharePoint as Nothing for UserID

Tags: sharepoint, events, logging

I got the following Exception in Application event log in sharepoint:

```
Exception Type: System.Exception
Message: User profile returned from SharePoint as Nothing for UserID 'S-1-5-21-59715478-2608859843-3034944815-2139'.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: NULL
HelpLink: NULL
Source: NULL
```

What is the solution?

Comment: More info please.  Are you sure this user exists?  Do you know the behavior necessary to reproduce the exception?

Answer (score 0):

That corresponds to a user in Active Directory who has either been removed from a group or has been disabled. There really isn't a "fix" for this. Just make sure that you don't leave site collections or owners as null when you do this.

Another reason why documentation and Architecture are very important for SharePoint!